# DataGrid 'no data' row: BindingExpression path error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm using a `DataGrid` in .Net3.5 to display several different sources of data that the user can switch between. Each data source uses a new DataGrid, but the code behind it all is common to all of them and so has no knowledge of the true contents of the data. Header titles and bindings to the objects in the DataGrid's ItemsSource are controlled by an XML file which makes the link when the `DataGrid` is first created.

I have also worked around the problem where no rows in a DataGrid causes the horizontal scrollbar to disappear. This is because I need the user to still be able to scroll across the headers in order to remove filters applied there which may have caused the lack of results. This is all done via a Converter which adds a collection of one EmptyRow if it ever sees that the currently bound collection returns no rows.

My problem is that this EmptyRow contains none of the properties which are held by the standard rows, so whenever it is added to the DataGrid there are obviously binding path errors even though those errors do not stop the row being added as a blank row.

None the less, I would prefer not to have the binding issue if someone can point me in the right direction.

**Update - converter to always return one row**

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values.Length == 2 && values[1] != null)
    {
        bool isEmpty;
        if (bool.TryParse(values[1].ToString(), out isEmpty) && isEmpty)
        {
            return new List<EmptyRow> {new EmptyRow()};
        }
    }
    return values.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**values** contains the current collection, and that collection's IsEmpty property. If the collection is empty it returns a collection of one EmptyRow rather than the empty collection. This is a converter for the generic DataGrid and the original collection could be one of several collection types. As a result I always get binding issues because EmptyRow does not satisfy the properties the DataGrid has been set up to expect.

Answer (score 0):

Updated as per last comments.

I can see two options here:

1. Create a distinct list of property names for all your objects and add them to your EmptyRow. Sounds nasty - but it's gonna work. This way you'll get a universal object. The drawback is you'll need to keep EmptyRow up to date whenever you'll modify your actual objects.
2. Change your objects to expandos, so rather than having

   string PropertyName
   {
     get;
     get;
   }

have an indexer like:

```
object Property[string propertyName]
{
  get { ... }
  set { ... }
}
```

having that in place you can always return something for an unknown property. That will force you to use Converter for every single value.

Comment: I already have a converter which returns the collection of a single EmptyRow object when no entries are detected in the 'real' collection. Changing that to Binding.DoNothing would then not return the EmptyRow resulting in no rows and the original problem of a disappearing horizontal scrollbar. Unless that's not what you intended?

Comment: How do you force your EmptyRow to come up on a grid? I'd have thought you're adding a dummy Item to your grid's ItemsSource collection (in which case it's more approapriate to use service as opposed to converter). going that route you should get no binding errors.

Comment: updated the original question to show my convert method (in a IMultiValueConverter implementation). Hopefully that shows what I've done. I don't actually know what type of rows are currently in any particular datagrid which is why I have the EmptyRow.